# How do I get my Encryption Certificate back?

Tags: encryption

I was using Windows 7 Professional. I encrypted a few personal pics and videos on my hard drive. Unfortunately someone deleted the encryption certificate.

Now I have installed Windows 8 and have formatted the previous Windows partition. My encrypted data is now available on the D drive but is not opening and I have no certificates. What should I do?

Comment: do you know if the user backed up the certificates?

Comment: Encryption sounds like a really good idea until you learn to backup your encryption keys. Then it becomes a really good idea. Potential usefulness vs. actual usefulness hinges on this one concept.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

If you haven't backed up the certificates and if you reinstalled your operating system, chances are high the files got overwritten. This means the certificates will not be recoverable from your hard drive. You can always try some file-recovery tools (like Undelete 360 ) to try and recover the certificates.